# Jquery UI Slider is there a way to make it bounce back to the default after you let go of the mouse

Tags: jquery, slider

For the Jquery UI Slider is there a way to make the handle bounce back to 0 after you let go of the mouse? I've seen this behavior on other sliders.  I try to change the slider value with onmouseup but it doesn't change.

```js
function sliderChange(elem,value){
elem.value=value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id='myslider' class='ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle' style='width:90%' type=range min=-10 max=10 step=1 value=0  oninput="sliderChange(document.getElementById('change'),this.value)" onmouseup="document.getElementById('change').value=0;document.getElementById('myslider').value=0;"><br>
    <input id="change" size="4" type="text" value="0">
```

Comment: Your code seems to already be doing what you ask. Can you be more clear about your goal, and why the current behaviour isn't what you require.

Comment: I just checked it on chrome it works. On firefox it doesn't.